# How to SFTP files from Linuxto a Windows attached network drive

Tags: windows, ssh, unix, sftp, mappeddrive

I need to send files from my Linux to a network drive that is attached to a Windows system via SFTP.

I want to know if I get the SFTP server running on Windows, how do I transfer a file from my linux machine to the network drive? After connecting to my Windows system, will simply including the Network drive's address in the path to transfer the files to work?

*Before anybody asks, I do not have permissions to fool around and try these things out myself, that's why I'm first asking:)*

Comment: Set up an SFTP server on linux then SCP to that from windows.

Comment: Or if direction is important (that is, linux -> windows) then consider using samba or something similar.

Comment: otoh, if it is a network share, you could mount it and then store the mount in fstab so it is there when you reboot the linux box.

Comment: Network share is attached to a Windows system. Could I sftp files from my linux system to the drive's address directly (through the Windows system)? I mean if I were to connect via SFTP to my Win system could I send a file to \\something\folder\ (which is the path of folder on my network drive) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arijit, you have the following

1. Share the network attached drive on the windows end and then
   mount the same on your linux box you need to have ntfs3G installed
   or an alternativate.
2. setup a ftps server on windows as windows
   does not support sftp and configure the network share as the default
   upload dir.

hope this helps